# Ler arquivo e atribuir cada linha em uma variável diferente

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu possuo o seguinte arquivo:

```
mensagem 1
mensagem 2
mensagem 3
mensagem 4
```

Gostaria de ler esse arquivo usando a linguagem JavaScript, e a cada linha, atribuir a uma variável diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `.split('\n')` para criar uma array onde cada linha fica separada.

Um exemplo seria:

```
fs.readFile('meuFicheiro.txt', 'utf8', (err, texto) => {
    var linhas = texto.split('\n');
    // agora podes usar dentro desta callback "linha", 
    // como uma array onde cada entrada é uma linha nova

});
```